# How do I separate the Month, Day, and Year fields from Advanced Custom Fields datepicker into a individual spans or divs?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, date, datepicker

Trying to build a simple event calendar for a band theme. Just wondering if there's a simple way to achieve this. I'm trying to make it as simple as possible, so I was trying to avoid using a free, or premium plugin.

Something I can style similar to this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HN0E.jpg)

Edit:

```
<span class="show_day">
<?php $date = new DateTime(get_field('show_date'));
echo $date->format('d'); ?></span>
<span class="show_month"><?php $date = new DateTime(get_field('show_date'));
echo $date->format('F'); ?></span>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry... It's linked now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
$date = new DateTime(get_field('date_field'));
echo $date->format('d F'); // should print 07 August
echo $date->format('h:i A'); // should print 09:30 PM
```

Have a look at [function.date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [datetime.format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

```
<span class="date"><?php echo $date->format('d F'); ?></span>
<span class="time"><?php echo $date->format('h:i A'); ?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to wrap the output in a span and add a class to each individual span?